# error: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pie-chart

```
const cases = document.querySelector('coronovirus-input');
const deaths = document.querySelector('deaths-input');
const recovered =document.querySelector('recovered-input');

const ctx = document.getElementById('mychart').getContext("2d");
let mychart = new CharacterData(ctx , {

  type:'pie',
  data: {
    labels : ['Active Cases','Deaths','Recovered'],
    datasets : [
      {
        label:'# of votes',
        data : [0,0,0],
        backgroundColor:['#2adece','#dd3b79','#ff766b'],
        borderWidth:1
      }
    ]
    
  }
});

const updateChartValue = (input, dataOrder) => {

  input.addEventListener ('change', e => {
    mychart.data.datasets[0].data[DataOrder] = e.target.value;
    mychart.update();
  });

};

updateChartValue(cases,0);
updateChartValue(deaths,1);
updateChartValue(recovered,2);
```

Hi Guys I cant solve this problem...
i want to make pie chart but I cant I am newbie to share any post in this website sorry if I did any mistakes
[This Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30Vea.png)

Comment: Your error is happening on Card.js at line 6 we need to be able to see this code to help. It that this line? `let mychart = new CharacterData(ctx , {`

Comment: My guess is it is related to JavaScript having https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CharacterData

Comment: The CharacterData abstract interface represents a Node object that contains characters. This is an abstract interface, meaning there aren't any objects of type CharacterData: it is implemented by other interfaces like Text, Comment, CDATASection, or ProcessingInstruction, which aren't abstract. - Means you can not call the new operator on it.

Comment: Yes line 6 is let mychart = new CharacterData(ctx , { @DerekLawrence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several issues in the code you posted, but most notably the constructor for initialising `mychart` should be `new Chart()` rather than `new CharacterData()` (possible typo due to auto-completion in your editor?).

Second, mind that selectors for element ids must be prefixed with #.

Finally the `updateChartValue` shows a mismatch in the case of the `dataOrder` argument and where it is used (capital 'D').

See solution here https://codepen.io/beezital/pen/zYEmKRG

```
const cases = document.querySelector('#coronovirus-input');
const deaths = document.querySelector('#deaths-input');
const recovered =document.querySelector('#recovered-input');

const ctx = document.getElementById('mychart').getContext("2d");
let mychart = new Chart(ctx , {

  type:'pie',
  data: {
    labels : ['Active Cases','Deaths','Recovered'],
    datasets : [
      {
        label:'# of votes',
        data : [10,20,30],
        backgroundColor:['#2adece','#dd3b79','#ff766b'],
        borderWidth:1
      }
    ]
    
  }
});

const updateChartValue = (input, dataOrder) => {

  input.addEventListener ('change', e => {
    mychart.data.datasets[0].data[dataOrder] = e.target.value;
    mychart.update();
  });

};

updateChartValue(cases,0);
updateChartValue(deaths,1);
updateChartValue(recovered,2);
```

Comment: Thank u very much

Comment: you're welcome Murad. Remember to accept this answer if it pleases you ;-)